# How to transform 3 bars (&#9866) into a "-X" using Transform and Transition

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
    #menu{  
        transition-duration: 1s;
        transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    #menu:hover div:nth-of-type(1){
        transform-origin: top;
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        transition-duration: 1s;
        transition-timing-function: ease-out;
        
    }

    #menu:hover div:nth-of-type(3){
        transform-origin: 1px bottom;
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
        transition-duration: 1s;
        transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    }

    #menu:hover div:nth-of-type(2){
        transform: translateX(-10px);
        transition-duration: 1s;
        transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
```

```html
<html>
      <head></head>
      <body>

                
                <div id="menu" >
                    <div class="bar" id="br1">&#9866</div>
                    <div class="bar" id="br2">&#9866</div>
                    <div class="bar" id="br3">&#9866</div>
                </div>
      </body>
```

The code is supposed to turn the 3 bars (&#9866) into a "-X" when we hover over the div(menu)
by using the transform element form CSS but It's somehow not doing so

Comment: If I am right you want to create hamburger menus!! [check this out](https://codepen.io/NikalLawde/pen/poPRgVe) I created them couple of months ago.

Comment: You need to set a size to your divs so they are no bigger than needed. At the moment they are all 100% wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/5x7kefwj/1/

We have made changes in the Html file, instead of using hexcode we have wrapped the bars in a span tag and also made changes in the CSS file by applying (`tranfrom-origin: right`) as it will set its position on right instead of center, and on hover, we have applied ( `transform: rotate( )` ) and now you will get the desired output.

Comment: Thank you so Much!!!!!, Can you also explain it a bit to me

Comment: We are glad that our solution helped you... :).

As explained above here we have wrapped the bars in a span tag and gave it 'transform: right' property, with this property the bars will set their position on the right side instead of the center. 

On hovering the mouse cursor over the menu we have reduced the width of 1 bar and applied the 'transform: rotate()' property on 2 bars to gain this 'X' shape.